# transition between 1+o(1) notation to little o and omega problem

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

I need to find $a\in\mathbb{N}$ so that ${3n-1 \choose 2n} = \omega(a^n)$ and ${3n-1 \choose 2n} = o((a+1)^n)$.

First, I showed that ${3n-1 \choose 2n} = \frac{1}{3} {3n \choose n}$.

I then used Stirling's approximation to get $${3n-1 \choose 2n} = \frac{1}{3}{3n \choose n} = \frac{1}{3}(1+o(1))(\frac{\sqrt6}{\sqrt{4 \pi n}}\cdot\frac{27^n}{4^n}) = \Theta(\frac{27^n}{\sqrt{n}4^n})$$

This is where I'm stuck.
I was also given the answer $a=6$, I'm just struggling to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from your approximation that for all $n \geq 1$,
$$
c_1  \cdot \frac{{6.75^n }}{{\sqrt n }} \le \binom{3n - 1}{2n} \le c_2  \cdot \frac{{6.75^n }}{{\sqrt n }}
$$
($6.75=27/4$) with some positive numbers $c_1, c_2$ that are independent of $n$. Thus,
$$
\frac{1}{{(6 + 1)^n }}\binom{3n - 1}{2n} \to 0,\qquad \frac{1}{{6^n }}\binom{3n - 1}{2n} \to  + \infty ,
$$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: I understand the first equation - it's the definition of the Theta notation. I still don't understand what led to the second equation though (Where did the limits come from?).

Comment: Use the upper bound to show the first limit, and use the lower bound to show the second one.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you!